# How can I go to the last visited page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a link called "BACK TO.." which will redirect to the previous page.I have used something like the following..

```
<div class="link2Back">
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl();?>">Back to ... </a>
</div>
```

But it is not working..It redirects to 404 not found page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to get the referer from the request and if it exists and is not an external URL, use it. If not, fall back to the base URL:

```
$url = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
if ((strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl()) !== 0)
    && (strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, true)) !== 0)
) {
    $url = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
}
```

This is a simplified version of the [_getRefererUrl()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L777) method of the controller base class.

Comment: Hello @fschmengler. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
<div class="back-button">
    <button onclick="history.back();" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Back') ?>" type="button">
        <span>
            <span><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></span>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Edit:
Here is another way:
http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/getting-the-last-url-and-determine-if-its-a-home-page-or-any-other-pages-in-magento/

Comment: Hello @Reinsch . It is working fine this way. Thanks. But I want to know whether it is possible in magento syntax ?

Comment: Well this is what is used in magento too.